# Apache2 not restarting - segmentation fault - ideas how to fix?

Tags: apache2

I have a new site running on digitalocean, ubuntu 14. I tried installing phpmyadmin using these instructions

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-14-04

From the shell, running the specified instructions caused the shell to freeze. Restarting shell in the digitalocean site then displayed a window from previous shell operation, asking me if I wanted to choose apache2. But the window was frozen and I could not proceed. I restarted the server, and now I can't access my website, seemingly because apache is down.

Apache won't restart, and I get message that apache couldn't reliably determine server's fully qualified domain name. Then it says segmentation fault (core dumped). When I read apache error log, it simply says it could not open a a logfile under my webroot. But when I navigate to the logfile I can open it.

So I am curious if I have caused myself quite the problem or if this is easily recoverable...

Thanks!

Brian

Comment: You will need to show the logs you checked so we can see exactly what the errors are.  The FQDN error shouldn't cause a segfault so something else will be the problem.  Update your answer with the end of your apache log.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out. I wasn't able to get a successful core dump to be saved, and after looking at the error log, it was actually showing something from a previous problem.

I think what happened was I mistakenly ran a phpmyadmin install command based on instructions for ubuntu 16, but I am on 14. So I ran a purge command on phpmyadmin , reinstalled according to 14 instructions and now everything is ok!

thanks, Brian